# How to fetch details from header string (PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS) in VSTO Addin outlook

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I need to create VSTO Addin for outlook. In that i need to get the information like DKIM status etc. My code is as follows.

```
var PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x007D001E";
Outlook.PropertyAccessor olPA = mail.PropertyAccessor;
var header = olPA.GetProperty(PR_TRANSPORT_MESSAGE_HEADERS);
MessageBox.Show(header );
```

I am getting all the informatio in the form of string but i need it in the form of properties. Like i need to access the info as 
`header.Received` and `header.Delivered-To`. How to achieve this?

Comment: You would need to parse the header programmatically.

Comment: can u please be more clear or could u give an example of how to do that

Answer (score 0):

In the simplest case, loop through all lines backwards. If the line starts wit ha space or a tab, append it to the previous line and delete the current line. Then loop through all lines and separate them into the header name (left of the first ":") and the header value (right of the first ":").

Comment: Is there any other way Dmitry that i can access the value like a property

Comment: Ehhh... No. What I outlined above will take less than a dozen lines of code.

Comment: Dmitry my requirement is to loop through all the mails present and check for a property which is present in that mail header. Now if i follow the above approach for each and every mail if i do parsing it would take much time right. Then it would be a problem for me

Comment: Could you please tell me that if any one have created class for this type of header responses.

Comment: Yes, you would have to do that for every email. No, it will not take much time. You can use one of many MIME parsers out there, but what I outlined below is as simple as it gets.